# JFrame not displaying correctly

Tags: java, sql, swing, jdbc, jframe

I am having design issues with my program.

Firstly a Jframe with the a combo box is displayed. The combo box is filled with town names you choose one and hit search.

The program then displays a jtable with the values from the tables. It generates the Jtable and the information but the jframe itself shows up as if no size parameters were set resulting in none of the content being shown until you manually increase the size by dragging it by the bottom right corner.

Here is the code for the Jtable

```
public class Display_All extends JFrame
{
    public Display_All(Object town)
    {
        Vector columnNames = new Vector();
        Vector data = new Vector();

        try
        {
            //  Connect to an Access Database


            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ire";
            String userid = "root";
            String password = "password";

            Class.forName( driver );
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url, userid, password );

            //  Read data from a table

            String sql = "(SELECT Activities_Name,       Activities_Email,Activities_Address_1,   Town, Activities_Phone ,Activities_Mobile, Activities_Web_Address, Activities_Owner FROM activities WHERE Town ='"+town+"')"
                    + "UNION ALL ( SELECT Attraction_Name, Attraction_Email, Attraction_Address_1, Town, Attraction_Phone, Attraction_Mobile, Attraction_Web_Address, Attraction_Owner FROM attractions WHERE Town = '"+town+"')"
                    + "UNION ALL ( SELECT BB_Name, BB_Email, BB_Address_1 ,Town, BB_Phone, BB_Mobile, BB_Web_Address, BB_Owner FROM bb WHERE Town = '"+town+"')"
                    + "UNION ALL ( SELECT Hotel_Name ,Hotel_Email ,Hotel_Address_1, Town, Hotel_Phone, Hotel_Mobile, Hotel_Web_Address, Hotel_Owner FROM hotels WHERE Town = '"+town+"')"
                    + "UNION ALL ( SELECT Pub_Name, Pub_Email ,Pub_Address_1, Town, Pub_Phone ,Pub_Mobile, Pub_Web_Address, Pub_Owner FROM pubs WHERE Town = '"+town+"')"
                    + "UNION ALL ( SELECT Restaurant_Name, Restaurant_Email, Restaurant_Address_1, Town, Restaurant_Phone, Restaurant_Mobile, Restaurant_Web_Address, Restaurant_Owner FROM restaurant WHERE Town = '"+town+"')"
                    + "UNION ALL ( SELECT Self_Catering_Name, Self_Catering_Email, Self_Catering_Address_1, Town, Self_Catering_Phone, Self_Catering_Mobile, Self_Catering_Web_Address, Self_Catering_Owner FROM self_catering WHERE Town = '"+town+"')";


            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names


            columnNames.addElement( "Business Name" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Email" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Address 1" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Town" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Phone" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Mobile" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Web Address" );
            columnNames.addElement( "Owner" );


            //  Get row data

            while (rs.next())
            {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

                data.addElement( row );
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println( e );
        }

        //  Create table with database data

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames )
        {
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

    //        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    //        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display_All frame = new Display_All("town");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

     public void run() {
        new Display_All("town").setVisible(true);
     }
    }
```

Can anyone shed light on what I am doing wrong?

I have tried alot of different things trying to get to the bottom of this but the the program doesn't seem to respond to anything I put into it?

Its hard to explain I would show pictures but my reputation is too low.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `pack()` can help you -> [JDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).

Comment: Don't use a JFrame for this. An application should only have a single main JFrame. Other child windows should be a JDialog with the main frame specified as the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either set the size of the JFrame, or pack the JFrame.

Also, you need to put your Swing components on the Event Dispatch thread (EDT).

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Display_All frame = new Display_All("town");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

            frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));  // or
            frame.pack();

            frame.setVisible(true);
        }       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. split logics for GUI and Database, column names could be defined before `try` - `catch` - `finally` block, because `ResultSetMetaData` seems like as (never is) isn't used
2. `rs.close();` and `stmt.close();` and `connection.close();` shoudl be closed in `finally block`
3. [`JTable`, `XxxTableModel` is based on 2D array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), then `Vector data = new Vector();` should be `Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();`
4. define as local variable (`JFrame`, `JTable`, `JScrollpane`), all Objects that is present still is visible in your GUI, during whole application time
5. see [InitialThread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), otherwise `JFrame.pack()` and `JFrame.setVisible(true)` should be wrapped into `invokeLater()`
6. `JTable` in `JScrollPane` doesn't returns proper `Dimension`, required to override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(x, y));` then `JFrame.pack()` returns proper coordinates for any `JComponent` wrapped in `JScrollPane`

Comment: @HeadlessProgrammer  [please to see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11858629/714968)

Answer (score 0):

This main method will allow you to me able to see the JFrame and will set it to the Look and Feel of your system. ie Windows OS, meaning the JFrame will look like a windows dialog box.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    mainWindow.setSize(500,300);
}
```

Comment: setVisible should be the last method called.

Comment: I tried that there and nothing happened :( Thanks though really appreciate the help